# What countable ordinals are called $\kappa_\alpha$?

Tags: lo.logic, notation, ordinal-numbers, ordinal-analysis

Jervell has a notation for countable ordinals up to the small Veblen ordinal using trees:

• Herman Ruge Jervell, [How to wellorder finite trees
and get good ordinal notations](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/mathematical/jervell/jervell_ordinal_notations.pdf), Berkeley Logic Seminar, 3 October 2008.

After illustrating this notation for various ordinals up to $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$, on page 13 he illustrates it for two ordinals that he calls $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_\omega$.  He calls them 'critical $\epsilon$-numbers'.  **What are these ordinals?**

I'll make a wild guess: $\kappa_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th solution of the equation

$$ \beta = \epsilon_\beta $$

where the [epsilon number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)) $\epsilon_\beta$ is, in turn, the $\beta$th solution of the equation

$$ \gamma = \omega^\gamma.$$

Am I right?

Separately: **how commonly used is this notation $\kappa_\alpha$ for certain countable ordinals?**  I've never seen it anywhere else.  Usually when people hit the first solution of $ \beta = \epsilon_\beta $ they introduce the [Veblen hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function#The_Veblen_hierarchy) and call it something like $\phi_2(0)$.

Comment: There might be one or two tags that are also relevant, maybe [tag:ordinal-analysis] or some other proof theory related tag.

Comment: Thanks.  I added ordinal analysis, mainly because experts in that may know the answer to this question.

Comment: Are you sure you linked to the right paper?  The PDF is not searchable so I might have missed it, but I couldn't find any occurrence of the word "critical" or of $\kappa_1$ or $\kappa_\omega$ in it. • Incidentally, if you're looking for good references on ordinal notations up to the small and large Veblen ordinals, I recommend Schütte's paper (see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/234769/17064)). Beyond that, it gets harder.

Comment: I also can't find it in the paper, but your guess is very plausible: I would call the critical $\varepsilon$-numbers the ordinals of the form $\varphi(2,\alpha)$. For your other question: I personally have never seen the notation $\kappa_\alpha$ for a countable ordinal that I recall (and I've looked at a fair bit of proof-theoretical literature).

Comment: Aargh, sorry, I linked to the wrong PDF!  I fixed the link; it's on page 13.   I should also try to understand Jervell's tree notation well enough that I can simply _figure out_ what he means by $\kappa_\alpha$.

Comment: Gro-Tsen - Thanks for the reference!  I'm writing a series of blog articles that will go up to the finite-variable Veblen functions, because there should be more expository accounts of this delightful nook of mathematics.  Ultimately there should be expository accounts that also fill in all the details, but I'm not doing that.  This article is nice: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/pete/courses/Formal-methods/2008-Fall/readings/transfinite-ordinals-notations.pdf.  But it deserves to be expanded!

Comment: @AsafKaragila given the small number of questions and followers, I doubt of the usefulness of 2 distinct tags ordinal-numbers and ordinal-analysis. Who would be interested in one and not the other?...

Comment: @YCor: Ordinal analysis is something very specific and related to proof theory (I, for example, am not particularly interested in the details of the field, however I do find it interesting on an anecdotal level); ordinal numbers can come up in all sort of places all across mathematics. But you do have a point, and the reason I didn't add the ordinal analysis tag in the first place is that I figured it might be very low on followers. However, one reason to still include it is because its relevance here. As a tag grows, its expert-base and followers-base grow with it.

Comment: In case the link to Jervell's notes goes dead, I've saved it at the Internet Archive: [How to wellorder finite trees and get good ordinal notations](https://web.archive.org/web/20240311141435/https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/mathematical/jervell/jervell_ordinal_notations.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I think I've blundered into an answer to my own question.  In this paper:

• Hilbert Levitz, [Transfinite ordinals and their notations: for the uninitiated](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/pete/courses/Formal-methods/2008-Fall/readings/transfinite-ordinals-notations.pdf).

the author writes:

> The first critical epsilon number is defined as follows.  Arrange the solutions of $\omega^x = x$ in order and call them $\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \dots$ etc. Then the first critical epsilon number is the smallest member of the sequence equal to own subscript.

Since Jervell calls the numbers $\kappa_\alpha$ "critical $\epsilon$-numbers", I conclude that he's probably talking about the same concept: $\kappa_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$th solution of $\epsilon_x = x$.

Comment: See also top p. 234 of [*An ordinal bound for the set of polynomial functions with exponentiation*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02485393) by Levitz (1978).  FYI, I've known about this paper for about 25 years, it being among the several hundred "large countable ordinal papers" I've photocopied over the years (since the mid 1980s), and just now I came across your question/answer when looking for a link to something online (hopefully Wikipedia, but not found) that mentions the well-known "critical number" terminology specifically for $\epsilon$-numbers. I love your 3-part essay on large ordinals!